# Tabs re_protection issue on Format columns & Format Rows, Auto filter

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba7

While reseting the password on current file using VBA, Once reprotected "Format columns & Format Rows, Auto filter" options are disabling. We not required these optons for all the files based on the requirement will enable those options & If password we shared with user will reset the password by macro in that time those options are dissabling. Any one can provide solution on my query. Thank you.

```
    Sub Main_Protect()
    
    Dim PWD As String
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    
    
    
    
    PWD = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Range("D1").Value
    
    'If PWD = "" Then
        'PWD = InputBox("Please Enter the password")
    'End If
        
    Set WB = Application.Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Cells(13, 1))
    
          ' Loop through all sheets in the workbook
    
    LR = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tab").Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tab").Range("A2:A" & LR)
    
    For Each cell In rng
    If cell > 0 Then
    
         WB.Activate
        
        Set ws = WB.Sheets(cell.Value)
        ws.Protect PWD,Contents:=True, UserInterfaceOnly:=True
        
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tab").Range("B" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tab").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = "Yes"
      
    
        End If
    Next cell
    
    MsgBox "Done"
    WB.Save
    WB.Close
    
    
    End Sub
```

Is there any option what ever options enabled on previous same options should be available after protection.

Answer (score 0):

To enable the expected functions when protecting a worksheet, please specify the related parameters accordingly.

```
    ws.Protect PWD, Contents:=True, UserInterfaceOnly:=True _
        , AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True _
        , AllowFiltering:=True
```

Microsoft reference document:

> [Worksheet.Protect method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.protect?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: Thankyou bro. That line code I have idea, but my condition is for all files no need to enable those options,only for few files. If we apply this line while resetting password, if that file not required those options also macro it will enable right.